# NX applications blocks thread when accessing store `micro-frontend` apps

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, nomachine-nx

I have an issue with my NX applications. Right now i have 3 apps. One is responsible from upload, one is responsible for export and last is responsible for store.

To run all those apps I am using NX. Right now i have an issue, that every time I want to use something from my store app  it is blocked. I have a Context where I am storing some state for component and it is reach for global state it is crashing one of my applications with some errors `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')`
This is calling to my Context provider and when I will stop using my store it is rendering without errors.
Not sure how i can split thread to make this working